# How to retrieve the RA (Router Advertisment) Received by My PC?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipv6, radvd

I want to see all the RA (Router Advertisment) Received by My PC.

Where I can found a uch information on my ubuntu linux system

Comment: Please do not cross-post.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use generic packet capture tools such as `wireshark` or `tcpdump`.

There are also specialized tools, `radvdump` (from radvd) and `rdisc6` (from ndisc6). The latter actually *requests* a RA immediately, while radvdump and other tools merely monitor what arrives on its own.